# Calculating Area and Circumference of a circle using a point class

Tags: java, class, constructor, point

I initially wrote the following Point class:

```
public class Point {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point (double x, double y) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

I tried to use the point class as a way of storing the origin of a circle so that later on I could calculate if 2 circles intersect:

```
public class Circle {

    double radius;
    Point origin;

    public Circle (Point origin, double radius) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.origin = origin;
    }  

    public double circumfurence (double radius) {
        return 2 * radius * Math.PI;
    }

    public double area (double radius) {
        return Math.PI * radius * radius;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Circle c = new Circle((3.0,3.0), 3.0);
        System.out.println(c.area());
        System.out.println(c.circumfurence());
    }

}
```

However, when I try to compile the two files I get the following error:

```
Circle.java:20: error: ')' expected
    Circle c = new Circle((3.0,3.0), 3.0);
                              ^
```

If I remove the brackets around **(3.0,3.0)** I get this error:

```
Circle.java:20: error: constructor Circle in class Circle cannot be applied to given types;
    Circle c = new Circle(3.0,3.0, 3.0);
               ^
required: Point,double
found: double,double,double
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

**EDIT**: Thanks but I still get the error:

```
Circle.java:21: error: method area in class Circle cannot be applied to given types;
    System.out.println(c.area());
                        ^
required: double
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Comment: Well for the second part again the solution is in the error message. Remove the `radius` argument to match the calling code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Circle` takes a `Point` instance as its first constructor argument

```
Circle c = new Circle(new Point(3.0,3.0), 3.0);
```

Comment: All these error messages clearly indicate the associated problem. In that case it is that the number of arguments for `area` dont match